# How does NPM handle version conflicts?

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install, node-modules

Since NPM version 3 node modules and dependencies are all installed at the same root level. But what if I install two modules that depend on two different versions of the same module? For instance, if I install async `npm i async@2.1.4`, which [requires lodash version 4.14.0](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/package.json#L21), then I install yeoman `npm i yo@1.8.5`, which [requires lodash version version 3.2.0](https://github.com/yeoman/yo/blob/master/package.json#L55), how does npm resolve this conflict?

Comment: "In that case, each dependency with a conflicting version on the same dependency would get its own, nested copy of that conflicting dependency. That's why we describe the install tree as maximally flat – it will still allow nesting in the case of conflicts."  Taken from a github issue in this topic.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

All the dependencies and the internal dependencies tries to get a place in the root of the `node_modules` unless there is a conflict with the same dependency, but different version. **When a conflict raises, it creates a sub `node_modules` under each dependency needed** and pushes conflicting internal libraries in it.

EXAMPLE:
Here, "A" internally depends on "alpha@v1.0" and "B" depends on "alpha@v2.0".
When you execute install A and B like below:

```
npm install A
npm install B

node_modules
|_ A
|_ alpha @v1.0
|_ B
|    |_ node_modules
|        |_ alpha @v2.0
|_ ...
```

NOTE: Another `node_modules` created under "B" inside the main node_module.

For more details: [visit this post](https://dev.to/shree_j/how-npm-works-internally-4012).

Comment: Is my understanding correct here in that if (continuing your example) one were to `npm install C` after the two before mentioned installs (of "A" and "B"), where "C" depends on "alpha@v2.0", then there would be two copies of "alpha@v2.0" (one under node_modules/B/node_modules/, other under "node_modules/C/node_modules/")?

Comment: If the project has 100 more dependencies which are depending on "alpha@v2.0", then would we have 102 copies of "alpha@v2.0" code within our project tree?

Comment: @ceremcem 
Yes, total 101 copies i.e., 1 under ***main node_modules/B/node_modules/*** & 100 more each under it's respective package, check this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-does-npm-handle-version-conflicts/

Comment: @whoami-fakeFaceTrueSoul How come the different versions aren't stored in node_modules and then linked also in B/node_modules? It would still resolve, right?

Comment: @Jack not sure why, but that's npm functionality not to maintain a dependency of a package in other packages `node_modules`.