# Is there an equivalent to NPM's "peerDependencies" in Python (preferably in setuptools)?

Tags: python, dependencies, setuptools, peer-dependencies

I am looking for a way to express something that resembles NPM's `peerDependencies` in `setuptools`.

My Python library is a plugin that should work with another Python library that I don't want to have as a dependency. Instead I'd like my end user to be responsible for it and install it by themselves. I can't find a proper way to express this in Python's `setuptools` (or any other build for that matter), to let my user "know" about the library

From my current understanding, this is a close approximation between the tools:

| NPM | setuptools |
| --- | --- |
| `dependencies` | `install_requires` |
| `optionalDependencies` | `extras_require` |
| `peerDependencies` | **???** |

I have two possible solutions, both of which I find lacking:

1. Use `extras_require` anyway

   Specify my requirements under an `extras_require` will do the job, but it feels like abusing it, because the user shouldn't install these extras.
2. Just document it

   Inform the user that they need to install that package separately. Feels lame too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, there is no need for that, as Python handles dependencies different anyway.

With npm/node you can have multiple versions of one package withing the same environment, if it required by one of the sub-dependencies ([How does NPM handle version conflicts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147243/how-does-npm-handle-version-conflicts))

This is not possible in Python. Only a single version of a library can be installed in the one environment. This means that the general issue that you are trying to [solve with peer-dependencies](https://nodejs.org/es/blog/npm/peer-dependencies/), can not happen.

My recommendation is to specify your dependencies as normal, but with a loose version specifier.

Comment: Good points! I have not given enough thought to python’s version conflicts resolution. So, basically if my plugin lib needs the external lib, it will be good to loosely specify it. The app will declare its more specific version if needed and they’ll settle on that one. The result is the same anyway.

Comment: We have an issue that there are different versions of the `torch` library depending on which version of CUDA your environment has installed.  Our library requires `torch`, but the user of our library is the only one who can determine which version of `torch` needs to be installed.  (Note: this is not "which version" like "2.0 or 3.0", nor environment like "windows vs linux", but environment like "what hardware driver do you have installed."  See this for more details: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/6409

Comment: In such a case, I would recommend to perform the checks in your library and then throw an error advising the user on which version of torch should be installed. Your library should "just" specify the full range of torch versions that it could theoretically support.

Answer (score 0):

The modern answer to this is that:

- If the dependency is required for your library/application to function, you should add it as a dependency (specifying as loose a version as possible, so that your users can have a different version of it if needed).
- If the dependency is required for optional features, you can specify one or more [extras](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/specifications/dependency-specifiers/#extras). The user can then opt-in to these, and if they do, the dependency you specify will also be installed.
- If the dependency is a drop-in replacement you only want to use if it's installed, you can use conditional imports ([`if find_spec("my_dependency"): ...`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.abc.MetaPathFinder.find_spec)) where appropriate in your code, and then it will be loaded if available, otherwise the fallback you define will be used.
  For example, you might want to use the [`regex`](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package if the user has it, otherwise fall back to the standard library's [`re`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), without forcing the user to install `regex` just for that.